# automatically insert header doc comments in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, headerdoc

Since XCode 5 now supports reading header comments directly from header files, it has become increasingly interesting, to document functionality in a consistent way.

I therefore try to find a tool that can automatically insert header doc comments in Objective C header files, but can't seem to find one?

Basically I would like a took that could write something like:

```
/*!
    <desc method.>
    @param parmA
        <desc of parmA>
    @param parmB
        <desc of parmB>
    @result
        <desc of result>
 */
- (CO2 *)doSomething:(typeName)parmA withSomething:(typeName)parmB;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this very handy Xcode plugin to write all the default comment code for you.

https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode

**EDIT**

As of Xcode 8, there is a new shortcut available that has the same behaviour as the VVDocumenter plugin.

Place the cursor above any function, class, struct,... and hit `⌘ + ⌥ + /`

This will generate a comment accordingly to where you placed the cursor.

Comment: Seems like the perfect solution! However I can't make it work. Instead of inserting a comment it seems to simply insert whatever I have in my clipboard. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes, you should download the master branch, build the VVDocumenter-Xcode target and restart Xcode after that. This worked for me.

Comment: ahh I found out that another tool I'm using (cut/paste files) was causing the problems. Seems like an excellent tool! Thanx